# Текущая дата в Label

Tags: xcode, swift3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать в label текущую дату на swift 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let currentDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"

self.myLabel.text = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
```

Comment: ругается на formatter, пишет Expected declaration

Comment: покажите скрин.

Comment: Скрин по ссылке http://s017.radikal.ru/i417/1609/36/d73d7f7d3ed9.png

Comment: весь этот код должен быть в каком то методе, где вы хотите менять текст в label. Например `viewDidLoad`